# How to properly optimise mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a web page that is divided into different sections. Each section has to show different results. These results are gotten from the database.
This is a sample data on SQLfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad98b/1

The following code is what comes to my mind but I'm afraid that it might somehow overload the server when this page is accessed multiple times by different people

```
$sectionA = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Main_Section WHERE section = `A` 
"); 
while ($row = $sectionA->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $sec_result_a = $sec_result_a.'<p>'.$id.'</p><h3>'.$name.'</h3>';
}

$sectionB = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Main_Section WHERE section = `B` "); 
while ($row = $sectionB->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $sec_result_b = $sec_result_b.'<p>'.$id.'</p><h3>'.$name.'</h3>';
}

$sectionC = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Main_Section WHERE section = `C` "); 
while ($row = $sectionC->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $sec_result_c= $sec_result_c.'<p>'.$id.'</p><h3>'.$name.'</h3>';
}
```

UP TO section Z

Is there a way I can Optimise this properly?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You does not seems to have any index on you table. Create `index` on `section` column. Also, provide some more information about you problem and the expected result.
What are the challenges your are facing? How many records you have in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's more to the picture, why not just query everything, ordered by section, to have the A-Z:

```
SELECT * FROM Main_Section ORDER BY section
```

... and then process the results with one loop, which could look something like this:

```
$sections = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Main_Section ORDER BY section"); 

while ($row = $sections->fetch_array())
{
    echo $row['section'] . ' ' . '<p>' . $row['id'] . '</p><h3>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '</h3>'; 
}
```